# Flowgorithm - Change a character in a string

Tags: flowgorithm

Is there a way to change a single character in a String?
In C programming you could do:

```
char s[4] = "abc";
s[0]='c';
```

Is there a way to manipulate a string in flowgorithm?
I get an error if I try it:

[image]

There is always the error that the string is not an array.
Maybe there is someone who got a hint to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Flowgorithm is often lacking in many aspects. Strings are not Arrays and cannot be indexed for writing. No idea why! But you can use `Char()` to get the i-th character in a string (whose type is a String with length 1). You can convert a 1 character long String into its ASCII code with `ToCode()` and you can move back from ASCII code to 1 character long String with `ToChar()`.
Additionally Arrays (also parameters) are mutable, while Strings are immutable. We can then make a `StringToArray()` function:

[image: StringToArray]

then a `ArrayToString()` function:

[image: ArrayToString]

Then put them together in a `SetChar()` function:

[image: SetChar]

You can use it like this:

[image: Main]

The XML version:

```xml
    <function name="Main" type="None" variable="">
        <parameters/>
        <body>
            <declare name="x" type="String" array="False" size=""/>
            <assign variable="x" expression="&quot;Test 123&quot;"/>
            <assign variable="x" expression="SetChar(x, 4, &quot;0&quot;)"/>
            <output expression="x" newline="True"/>
        </body>
    </function>
    <function name="ArrayToString" type="String" variable="s">
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="a" type="Integer" array="True"/>
        </parameters>
        <body>
            <declare name="s" type="String" array="False" size=""/>
            <declare name="j" type="Integer" array="False" size=""/>
            <assign variable="s" expression="&quot;&quot;"/>
            <for variable="j" start="0" end="Size(a)-1" direction="inc" step="1">
                <assign variable="s" expression="s &amp; ToChar(a[j])"/>
            </for>
        </body>
    </function>
    <function name="SetChar" type="String" variable="s">
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="s" type="String" array="False"/>
            <parameter name="i" type="Integer" array="False"/>
            <parameter name="c" type="String" array="False"/>
        </parameters>
        <body>
            <declare name="a" type="Integer" array="True" size="Len(s)"/>
            <call expression="StringToArray(s,a)"/>
            <assign variable="a[i]" expression="ToCode(c)"/>
            <assign variable="s" expression="ArrayToString(a)"/>
        </body>
    </function>
    <function name="StringToArray" type="None" variable="">
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="s" type="String" array="False"/>
            <parameter name="a" type="Integer" array="True"/>
        </parameters>
        <body>
            <declare name="j" type="Integer" array="False" size=""/>
            <for variable="j" start="0" end="Len(s)-1" direction="inc" step="1">
                <assign variable="a[j]" expression="ToCode(Char(s,j))"/>
            </for>
        </body>
    </function>
```